# Ajax post to a php file in a directory not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax request for a project and i has lot of problem to make it working I sommetime receive some error 500 (Internal Server Error), but finally everything works until I wanted to move my scripts into a directory.

Here is my Ajax works :

```
    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
        callback_like(xhr.responseText, receive);
         location.reload();
      }
    };
    xhr.open("POST", "like.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var data = "like=" + receive;
    xhr.send(data);
```

And this one doesn't work :

```
    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
        callback_like(xhr.responseText, receive);
         location.reload();
      }
    };
    xhr.open("POST", "script/like.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var data = "like=" + receive;
    xhr.send(data);
```

Error message in the console : POST: 'url' 500 (Internal Server Error)

I already tried to set all the right to the directory but nothing change..

Thanks

Comment: can't debug the error thrown on server by examining client side code. Check your error logs and also implement error display output and examine actual response in browser dev tools network

Comment: is the directory `script` a sub-directory of the current working directory or `root-relative`?

Comment: @RamRaider Yes is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An internal server error means that there is probably an error in your code. Any references or includes of other files that need to be adjusted? If the file wouldn´t be found you´d get a 404 Not Found in your response.

Enable error output in php to get a more detailed error message from php.

Comment: Thank you  so much it was an include with a wrong path I didn't know that the Ajax call was going to the url

Comment: You´re welcome. Please mark my answer as correct then.